# How to find previous route angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

It would be ideal to have some service like `ActivatedRoute` snapshot to find previous route?

Any idea?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no such Service but there are many workarounds to get the previous route or URL, please take a look at this https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11268

Comment: This question isn't at all a duplicate of the link provided. The link is for detecting an event (routing change) whereas this question is looking for a property (previous navigation location).